# Creating an anchor point on a div with an offset in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get my link to go to an anchor point on another webpage, in this case a div with a unique id. However, as there is a menu with CSS positioning set as fixed (over the top of the div), I need to offset my positioning of where this 'top' is in effect. I have tried the following code but no luck. Any help welcome

```
 <a href="contact-us.html#book" class="book">Book a Place</a>
```

with some JQuery as this in a document ready;

```
$('a[href^=".book"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('a[href^=".book"]')` attempts to select an `a` element whose `href` attribute begins with ".book". Your `a` element's `href` begins with "contact-us" and doesn't contain ".book" at all. `.book` by itself however is a class selector, and attempts to select the element whose `class` attribute is equal to "book". Therefore, I think what you meant to do was simply:

```
$('a.book').on('click',function (e) { ... })
```

---

After changing that, your `a` element has no `hash` property. To get the `#book` value from your `a` element's `href` you'd have to extract that separately. Bearing in mind that you'd have to already be on /contact-us.html for this to work, you could instead change your `href` to just `#book`:

```
<a href="#book" class="book"> ... </a>
```

Then pull the entire `href`:

```
var target = this.href;
```

Comment: I have amended the first line but now the a link doesn't work at all?

Comment: I have removed the (e) as it is this that prevents it from navigating to the other page where my id lives. However, this still doesn't give an offset position to my starting/scroll point :(